# Dockerize springboot application in java

Tags: java, docker

I have a java spring boot application. I want to dockerize it but facing an issue. Below mention is my docker file and the error that I'm facing:

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

to run this I have use below commands

```
docker build -t "test:dockerfile" .
docker run -p 9000:9000 "test:dockerfile"
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/diem/wallet/WalletApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Please let me know that where I'm doing it wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have version mismatch between JDK used to compile the app (probably 11), and JRE used to run it in the container (that one is of v8)
Either

1. Use higher java version in your docker container (use newer image than 8)
2. Use JDK8 to compile your java application

Comment: how I can take higher java version in docker

Comment: You can use alpine jdk11 https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11/

Comment: Is there any change in my docker file? I have pulled that image

Answer (score 0):

Your steps are correct. The issue is in mismatching of use of **jdk version for compilation and execution**. Make both jdk version same.

**Step 01:**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN addgroup -S spring && adduser -S spring -G spring
USER spring:spring
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**Step 02: Build, Run**

```
docker build -t "test:dockerfile" .
docker run -p 9000:9000 "test:dockerfile"
```

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: You can simply set/change environment variables of your docker image by using the ENV command in your Dockerfile:
`ENV JAVA_HOME /path/to/java`